# Not able to upload file in PHP

Tags: php, forms

I am unable to upload file in live server. Means it does moves in my local machine but it does not get stored in the live server. database entry is also filled but yet it will not be saved.

```
$authorityLocation="files/authority/";
if(isset($_FILES['Authority'])){
      $errors= array();
      $file_name = $_FILES['Authority']['name'];
      $file_size =$_FILES['Authority']['size'];
      $file_tmp =$_FILES['Authority']['tmp_name'];
      $file_type=$_FILES['Authority']['type'];
      $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['Authority']['name'])));

      $expensions= array("docx","doc","pdf");

      if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){
         $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a Word or pdf file.";
      }

      if($file_size > 50097152){
         $errors[]='Max File size 50 GB';
      }


$date = date_create();
$datetime=date_timestamp_get($date);

$Pan_card = $Pancard;

if (file_exists($authorityLocation."authority ".$Pan_card.$file_name)) {
echo "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>GST</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
   <H3>
      Thank You For Your Keen Interest Again!!! You Have Already Submitted The Details.
   </H3>
   <H4>
      Our Team Will Contact You Soon
   </H4>
</center>
</body>
</html>";
exit();
} else {

    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, "files/authority/".$Pan_card." authority ".$file_name);
         $authorityPath = $authorityLocation.$Pan_card." authority ".$file_name;

}

}
```

Comment: Check permissions of target folder on "live" server. PHP code not running as a root - so you have to give permission to write for the user which running PHP, usually "apache".

Comment: perhaps the folder you are writing to as @Nosyara mentioned is write protected.

Comment: You need to check the location `$authorityLocation` is writable or not, Your live server is open for file upload or not.

Comment: It was a permission issue. Thank You Very Very Much

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.